# Keep checkbox checked after form submit

Tags: php, html, forms, checkbox

I have a page where I am displaying sql results as a table. I have it so that all the options are checked on default. However, when the user unchecks some locations and submits the form, he/she won't know what locations they're filtering on because all the checkboxes will still be checked. How can I make it so that only the checkboxes that were checked retain their value after the form is submitted?
Thank you

Here's my page so far:

```
   <?php 

   $start=_GET['start'];
   $end=_GET['end'];

   if(empty($start)){
      $start=date("Ym");
    }
  if(empty($end)){
    $end=date("Ym");
 }


 $places=array();
if(!empty($_GET['cities'])){
    foreach($_GET['cities'] as $loc){
  array_push($places,$loc);
  }
}else{
   $places=('CHI','DET','LA','NYC','DALLAS','SPR','PHI');
}

?>

//html
<form method='GET'>
  START:<input type='text' name='start' value= '<?$start?>'>
   END: <input type='text' name='end' value='<?$end?>'>
 <input type='checkbox' name='cities[]' value='CHI' checked>CHICAGO
 <input type='checkbox' name='cities[]' value='DET' checked>DETROIT
 <input type='checkbox' name='cities[]' value='LA' checked>LAS ANGELES
 <input type='checkbox' name='cities[]' value='NYC' checked>NEW YORK
 <input type='checkbox' name='cities[]' value='DALLAS' checked>DALLAS
 <input type='checkbox' name='cities[]' value='SPR' checked>SPRINGFIELD
 <input type='checkbox' name='cities[]' value='PHI' checked>PHILIDELPHIA
 <input type='submit' value='Filter'>
 </form>

 <?
 $SQL="SELECT NAME,
     ID,
     PHONE,
     EMAIL,
     EVENT,
     LOCATION
 FROM SHOPPERS
 WHERE LOCATION IN ('".implode("', '", $places)."')
 AND EVENT BETWEEN '{$start}' and '{$end}'
 AND ID BETWEEN '25687' AND '28050'
  ";

   //and then fetch array to print out results...
  .....
  ?>
```

Comment: i hope with the help of ajax form submission you will solve your problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than hard-coding your "checked" attribute into each of your `<input type="checkbox">` fields, you should be using PHP to determine if the `GET` variable associated with each field was passed to the script. In that case, you want to append the `checked` attribute to your `<input>` field. You can accomplish this by using a ternary operator right inside the field, as such:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='cities[]' value='CHI' <?= (in_array('CHI', $places)) ? 'checked' : ''; ?> >CHICAGO
<input type='checkbox' name='cities[]' value='DET' <?= (in_array('DET', $places)) ? 'checked' : ''; ?> >DETROIT
<input type='checkbox' name='cities[]' value='LA' <?= (in_array('LA', $places)) ? 'checked' : ''; ?> >LAS ANGELES
<input type='checkbox' name='cities[]' value='NYC' <?= (in_array('NYC', $places)) ? 'checked' : ''; ?> >NEW YORK
<input type='checkbox' name='cities[]' value='DALLAS' <?= (in_array('DALLAS', $places)) ? 'checked' : ''; ?> >DALLAS
<input type='checkbox' name='cities[]' value='SPR' <?= (in_array('SPR', $places)) ? 'checked' : ''; ?> >SPRINGFIELD
<input type='checkbox' name='cities[]' value='PHI' <?= (in_array('PHI', $places)) ? 'checked' : ''; ?> >PHILIDELPHIA
```

Comment: When I did this, it keeps giving me an error, saying unexpected ';'

Comment: Sorry, I was missing a closing parenthesis around the first argument of the ternary operator. I've updated the code now; hopefully it should work.

Comment: Thank you! It was giving me an error at first because the array should be listed as the second argument not the first, but when I fixed that it works :)

Answer (score 1):

you could send the parameter which checkbox is checked in GET request,
and check it in your page
e.g

```
if ($_GET['param1']==1) // checked
{
?>
<input type='checkbox' name='cities[]' value='CHI' checked>CHICAGO
<?
else
?>
<input type='checkbox' name='cities[]' value='CHI' >CHICAGO
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$citiesGroup = array();
$citiesGroup['CHI'] = 'CHICAGO';
$citiesGroup['DET'] = 'DETROIT';
$citiesGroup['LA'] = 'LAS ANGELES';
$citiesGroup['NYC'] = 'NEW YORK';
$citiesGroup['DALLAS'] = 'DALLAS';
$citiesGroup['SPR'] = 'SPRINGFIELD';
$citiesGroup['PHI'] = 'PHILIDELPHIA';

$citiesChecked = array();
if (!empty($_GET['cities'])) {
    foreach ($_GET['cities'] as $cityCode) {
        $citiesChecked[] = $cityCode;       
    }
}
else {
    foreach ($citiesGroup as $key => $value) {
        $citiesChecked[] = $cityCode;       
    }
}
?>
<?php
foreach ($citiesGroup as $cityId => $cityName) {
    $chekced = in_array($cityId, $citiesChecked) ? 'checked="checked"' : '';
?>
<input type='checkbox' name='cities[]' value='<?php echo $cityId;?>' <?php echo $chekced;?>><?php echo $cityName;?>
<?php
}
?>
```

Get all checkboxed HTML in array and loop over it.

Above is the working code.